# log to both stdout and file in docker with laravel 5.2 and php 5.6

Tags: laravel, docker, file, logging, stdout

I found if i change driver path to 'php://stdout', I will not found logs in logs file.

```
    'log' => env('APP_LOG', 'daily'),

    'log_max_files' => 30,

    'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

My log configuration right now. I wanna keep these log files and I wanna see if I can see logs put out in stdout at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function(\Monolog\Logger $monolog) {
    $formatter = new \Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter(null,null,false,true);
    $stdOut = new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout',\Monolog\Logger::DEBUG);
    $stdOut->setFormatter($formatter);
    $monolog->pushHandler($stdOut);

    $file = storage_path('logs/mono-'. Date('Y-m-d', time()) . '.log');
    $monolog->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($file));

});
```

Do it like that, Theoretically can print log both side.